# White space between toolbar and searchbar

Tags: android

I am using this link for customized toolbar and tabs - http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/.

I also added a searchbar for search purposes above listview.I set the searchbar at layout_alignParentTop
Problem is there is white gap between the tabs and the searchbar.[Below Image is my emulator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfqza.png)

enter code here

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
                android:text="StoreDe"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="17.3sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="127dp"

                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/icn_dropdown" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                android:background="@drawable/icn_options"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="#f5f5f5"
            app:theme="@style/TabTheme"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_text"
            android:layout_above ="@+id/searchBar"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#d3d3d3"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:gravity="right|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="140dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            >

        </EditText>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/icnsearch"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="135dp"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: So you wanted first to be the toolbar then the tablayout then the viewpager and then the searchbox right? because it doesnt see to be in the right order

Comment: Thank You very much!! You saved my day!!!

Comment: I saw this afterwards but my toolbar title is missing now if I put view pager below appbarlayout